# Projects not "linked" the solution in TFS

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2019

For a very strange reason, I added two projects to a solution is managed by the TFS, but these project never got added to TFS (*I know, because there's no lock icon next to the project name*)

I followed some article and managed to add the projects to the folder on TFS, but these two new projects are still not being managed by the TFS.

Comment: Would you please mark your answer? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT...I just did...not sure if you knew, but stackoverflow has a policy that the poster cannot accept his/her own until 24+ hours after the initial question is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question:

File -> Source Control -> Add Selected Project to the Source Control

After that check-in the project.

Vola!